# Move First Char of String to End of String Using MySQL Functions

Tags: mysql, string, function

I'm trying to find an optimized way to move first Character of a Column to end of it, if first Character was '@' , Just when Showing data in DBGrid (Not permanently in database).

There are many Functions in MySQL, but I want to find the best way!

I show many (about 2000) records in DBGrid. Does it affect performance ?!

Comment: In which way you are trying please specify

Comment: We can't tell that easily. Just try different ways and measure. You should also consider to handle this on application level. Usually this is faster.

Comment: Did you write any code?

Comment: Yeah,My Code is like this:
`SELECT (CASE WHEN ASCII(MyColumn)=64 THEN (CONCAT(SUBSTR(MyColumn,2),'@')) ELSE MyColumn END) FROM MyTable;`
But I think @fancyPants is right. It is better to handle it in application level !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ASCII(MyColumn)=64 THEN (CONCAT(SUBSTR(MyColumn,2),'@')) ELSE MyColumn END) FROM MyTable;
```

`p.s:64 is ascii code for '@'`

But I think @fancyPants is right. It is better to handle it in application level !

I will use OnGetText Event in Dataset to handle it in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. I would not expect it to materially affect performance on 2000 rows:

```
select concat(substr(your_column,2),left(your_column,1))
from your_table
```